# Regular expression to search for not-a-specific-sequence-of-characters

Tags: regex, bash

I am looking for a regular expression that matches "not-a-specific-sequence-of-characters". A solution suddenly dawned on me (after a few years!) I am running bash on a Macintosh computer.

As an example, I want to match the word *Path* as long as it is not preceded by the word *posix* or *Posix*. Here is the regular expression I came up with:

```
[^[:space:]]*([^x]|[^i]x|[^s]ix|[^o]six|[^Pp]osix)Path
```

I would like to ask if there might be a more efficient or otherwise better approach. This approach can become somewhat cumbersome the longer the "not" sequence of characters is.

Comment: What flavor of regular expressions are you using? Or equivalently, are you doing this with grep, pcregrep, Perl, pure bash (`[[ x =~ y ]]`), etc.?

Comment: I primarily use the extended grep and extended sed that come with Mac OS X (currently on version 10.9).

Comment: I revised the regular expression in the main post to correct an obvious flaw. The current regex does what I had intended, namely to search for a whole word ending in Path as long as it is not preceded by posix or Posix.

Answer (score 1):

Perl regexes have handy ["look-around"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) features.

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?<![pP]osix)Path' file
```

GNU grep has a `-P` flag to enable perl-compatible regular expressions, but OSX does not have GNU tools by default.

A straightforward technique is to filter the output of grep:

```
grep 'Path' file | grep -v '[pP]osixPath'
```

Comment: Your grep solution works perfectly. It is so simple, so obvious, and so effective that it never occurred to me! Thank you.